# Use of PHP built-in ltrim() to remove a single character

Tags: php, string, function, built-in

Is there a simple way to use `ltrim()` to remove a single instance of a match instead of all matches?

I'm looping through array of strings and I'd like to remove the first, and only first, match (vowels in this case):

```
ltrim($value, "aeiouyAEIOUY");
```

With default behavior the string `aardvark` or `Aardvark` would be trimmed to be `"rdvark"`. I'd like result to be `"ardvark"`.

I'm not bound to ltrim by any means but it seemed the closest built-in PHP function. It would be nice of `ltrim` and `rtrim` had an optional parameter "limit", just saying... :)

Comment: aaeezz should the result be aezz or aeezz ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use preg replace it has a limit option

eg

```
$value = preg_replace('/^[aeiouy]/i', '', $value, 1);
```

Comment: This is actually better than `{1}` I think. Less to parse. Could the downvote be for the double quotes in the second parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions is probably overkill, but:

```
$value = preg_replace('/^[aeiouy]/i', '', $value);
```

Note the `i` makes it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ltrim` to do this for the reasons you say, nor can you use `str_replace` (which also has no limit).  I think it's easiest just to use a regex:

```
$value = preg_replace('/^[aeiouy]/i', '', $value);
```

However if you really don't want to do that, you can use a substring, but you would have to check the position of any of those strings in the string in a loop as there is no php function that does such a check that I know of.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have restrictions on how I remove first character. I'm simply new at PHP and not familiar enough with all the functions yet. preg_replace works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `preg_replace` function:

```
<?php
    $value = preg_replace('/^[aeiouy]/i', '', $value);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several way you can go about doing what you are looking to do.

Perhaps most straightforward would be a regular expression replacement like this:

```
$pattern = '/^[aeiouy]{1}/i';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $original_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the most efficient way (so ignore my regular expressions answer):

```
if (strpos('aeiouyAEIOUY', $value[0]) !== false) $value = substr($value, 1);
```

Or,

```
if (stripos('aeiouy', $value[0]) !== false) $value = substr($value, 1);
```

Comment: I like the regex version better.

Comment: +1. I'm suspecting this one would be faster than RegEx. Benchmark, anyone?

Comment: @Geo the regex version is consistently about 20% slower, but 1 million operations for both only takes about a second, so there is unlikely to be a speed benefit in this case.